# Restrict Kendo window from going outside of browser window screen

Tags: kendo-ui

If I drag a kendo window in upward direction the kendo window stops being dragged once kendo window top aligns browser window top, that is min top position is 0. I want similar behavior if I drag the kendo window to left, right or downward direction, window should always stay within the browser window (do not want scrolls to browser window).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After visiting documentation on Kendo site I have got an hint to implement the solution. Here is link to [Restrict Windows Position](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/window/how-to/restrict-windows-position)
Idea is to listen to drag event on Window and based on your condition adjust left and top of window.